# WPF : Bind DataGrid Inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which will have several datagrids inside. 
Want to get the binding to work, but for some reason the contents are not displayed:

```
 UserControls.iMRxMRDataGrid ucObj = new UserControls.iMRxMRDataGrid();
 ChartDescriptiveClass.PartName="test";
 ucObj.DataContext = ChartDescriptiveClass;
```

inside usercontrol:

```
  public partial class iMRxMRDataGrid : UserControl
    {
        public iMRxMRDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="iMRxMRDataUC" x:Class="SPCLibrary.UserControls.iMRxMRDataGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"             
             >
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>          
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="iMRxMRDataGri" DataContext="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=iMRxMRDataUC}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>               
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PartName}" Width="Auto" Header="PartName" IsReadOnly="True" />   <!--This will not work-->             
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>      
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.PartName,ElementName=iMRxMRDataUC}" Width="40px" Height="30px"/>  <!--This works-->      
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The class looks like this( one member per property):

```
public class ChartDescriptiveValues
    {
        //iMR & xMR
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public double Average{ get; set; }
        public double LSL { get; set; }
        public double USL { get; set; }
   }
```

The textBlock binding however works.(added this to test that the binding is working at all).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Binding of DataGridTextColumn bind your column to property in DataGrid.ItemsSource, so you must set ItemsSource or rethink about what you want.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="iMRxMRDataGri" ItemsSource={Binding SomeCollection} DataContext="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=iMRxMRDataUC}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>               
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyInDataModelOfSomeCollection}" Width="Auto" Header="PartName" IsReadOnly="True" />          
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Well.. the thing is that i dont really know how to do a binding like that.

I have a Class that i set to UserControl.DataContex = MyClass .
Now i need to bind the contents to the DataGrid which is a child of the usercontrol.

Comment: @Raunts You set DataContext for User Control, so DataContext for DataGrid is not necessary. For example, Text="{Binding PartName}" will work

Comment: deleting everything except the text="{Binding PartName}" , is not working. The textBlock that i have included..works just fine. But there is something with the datagrid.

Comment: updated the 1st post. Included how the class looks like.